# Grade xblock from another diagno app

Tags: openedx

Is there any way to grade an xblock outside of it, for example, from another edX django application? Or post an answer to it from outside.

Comment: You really need to clarify what you want to do. What kind of xblock do you want to grade? In Open edX, XBlocks do not store their own grades, but instead they store the answer for each user. Do you want to modify the answer of an xblock for a particular user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Submissions for it

```
from submissions import api
from student.models import anonymous_id_for_user

submission_id = {"item_id": xblock.location,
                 "item_type": 'xblock',
                 "course_id": course_id,
                 "student_id": anonymous_id_for_user(user, course_id)}
submission = api.create_submission(submission_id, {'comment': 'some comment'}, attempt_number=1)
api.set_score(submission['uuid'], grade, weight))
```

It wasn't exactly what I need but it was the best solution open edX can give.

**Pros and cons:**

Pros: in progress of the course you'll see grading for that xblock and edx will consider this xblock as passed

Cons: xblock won't consider himself as passed, so when student open it he'll be able to pass it again, but my xblocks are not shown to students so it's not a problem for me